# simplifying the Code

Tags: javascript, dom

The code that I have is getting a little long, I think there is a way to simplify it, take a look on it:

```
var slidernav = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
slidernavinital = 20;
slidernavadd = 30;
slidernav[0].style.top = slidernavinital + slidernavadd*0 + 'px';
slidernav[1].style.top = slidernavinital + slidernavadd*1 + 'px';
slidernav[2].style.top = slidernavinital + slidernavadd*2 + 'px';
slidernav[3].style.top = slidernavinital + slidernavadd*3 + 'px';
slidernav[4].style.top = slidernavinital + slidernavadd*4 + 'px';
slidernav[5].style.top = slidernavinital + slidernavadd*5 + 'px';
slidernav[6].style.top = slidernavinital + slidernavadd*6 + 'px';
slidernav[7].style.top = slidernavinital + slidernavadd*7 + 'px';
slidernav[8].style.top = slidernavinital + slidernavadd*8 + 'px';
slidernav[9].style.top = slidernavinital + slidernavadd*9 + 'px';
slidernav[10].style.top = slidernavinital + slidernavadd*10 + 'px';
slidernav[11].style.top = slidernavinital + slidernavadd*11 + 'px';
```

Isn't possible to do Something like this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('li')[x].style.top = 20 + 30*x + 'px';
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Wrap it in a `for` loop.

```
for(var i = 0; i < sliderNav.length; i++) {
    sliderNav[i].style.top = sliderNavInitial + sliderNavAdd*i + "px";
}
```

I think you should pick up an Intro to Programming book, though, if you didn't know about loops (what's the point of a computer if it doesn't take care of the repetitive stuff for you?)

EDIT: By the way, the `for` loop is shorthand for the following `while` loop construct:

```
var i = 0;
while(i < sliderNav.length) {
    sliderNav[i].style.top = sliderNavInitial + sliderNavAdd*i + "px";
    i++;
}
```

It just puts all of the "bookkeeping" on the first line of the loop so you can more easily predict how many times it will loop through. (A while loop just loops until the condition is met, and then stops, so if you forgot to include the `i++;` part, it will never stop.)

Comment: Very Nice Dude, thanks a lot. It Worked just fine! Btw its slidernavinital not sliderNavInitial, but its okay! Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 1):

Use a loop to cycle though the elements.

```
var slidernav = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
slidernavinital = 20;
slidernavadd = 30;
for (var n = 0; n<slidernav.length; n++) {
    slidernav[n].style.top = slidernavinital + slidernavadd*n + 'px';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a for

like this

```
var ln = slidernav.length;
for(var i = 1;i<=ln;i++)
{
    slidernav[i].style.top = slidernavinital + slidernavadd*i + 'px';
}
```

it a very simple proggraming construction.